# Scala method returning a Future

Tags: scala, promise, future

The following method that I have that makes use of the async library:

```
def myMethod(param: Long, isTru: Boolean): Future[Option[MyType]] = async {

  if (isTru) {
    val promise = Promise[Option[MyType]]

    val myFuture = doSomething(param)

    myFuture.onComplete {
      case Success(succ) => {
        promise.success(Some(MyType(param, succ)))
      }
      case Failure(fail) => promise.failure(fail)
    }

    promise.future // fails here
  }
  else {
    None
  }
}
```

It fails compilation with the error that:

```
[error] found: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[MyType]]
[error] required: Option[MyType]
```

which I do not understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like this, without promises and async

```
  def myMethod(param: Long, isTru: Boolean): Future[Option[MyType]] = {

    if (isTru) {
      doSomething(param).map(res => Some(MyType(param, res)))
    }
    else {
      Future.successful(None)
    }
  }
```

promises are actually rarely used

or if you want to use async do it like this:

```
  def myMethod(param: Long, isTru: Boolean): Future[Option[MyType]] = async {

    if (isTru) {
      val myFuture = doSomething(param)
      val myResult = await(myFuture)

      Some(MyType(param, myResult))
    }
    else {
      None
    }
  }
```

Whole point of using async block is that what you return from it is some type you want (probably not a Future) and then it is wrapped inside one. So if you need `Option[MyType]` return it, and it will be wrapped inside a Future to give you expected `Future[Option[MyType]]`. What makes async usefull is the await() function that changes `Future[T]` to `T` that you can use normally, without mapping and other things like that, it's sometimes more readable than nesting a lot of flatMaps.

Optionally, your code should work if you just wrap `promise.future` in `await()` like this `await(promise.future)` but this solution is pretty ugly to me.

Comment: The problem is that my await calls are in the yield block and I cannot use await in that context. The example that I have shown above is just a simplified version!

Comment: well then show unsimplified and maybe we can figure something out. Await certainly has its limitations.

Comment: here it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823943/scala-synchronising-asynchronous-calls-with-future

Answer (score 1):

Type `Option` is not type `Future`, note the `if-else` expression,

```
if() {...
  promise.future // fails here
}
else {
  None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both branches of 'if' statement should return either Option[MyType], if you use async {...} or Future[Option[MyType]], then you don't need async